# bash loop through list of numbers except given number

Tags: bash, loops

to loop through a continous list of numbers in bash I can do

```
for s in $(seq 1 5);do
   echo ${s}
done
```

to loop through a continous list of numbers leaving a given number out in python I can do:

```
list = [s2 for s2 in range(6)[1:] if s2 != s1]
for s1 in list:
   print s1
```

where list contains all numbers in range except s1

How do I do the same in bash?

Comment: add an `if` statement (or equivalent) inside the loop?

Comment: Use `for ((i=1; i<=5; i++))` instead of using an external command that has to generate the full list all at once.

Comment: A question that shows a complete problem, thought and arguably some research. Good job OP. You made my day a little better today and I think that's very nice.

Answer (score 7):

Just use `continue` to skip this step:

```
for s in {1..5}                 # note there is no need to use $(seq...)
do
   [ "$s" -eq 3 ] && continue   # if var is for example 3, jump to next loop
   echo "$s"
done
```

This returns:

```
1
2
4             # <--- 3 is skipped
5
```

From [Bash Reference Manual → 4.1 Bourne Shell Builtins](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins):

> **continue**
>
> ```
> continue [n]
> ```
>
> Resume the next iteration of an enclosing for, while, until, or select
>   loop. If n is supplied, the execution of the nth enclosing loop is
>   resumed. n must be greater than or equal to 1. The return status is
>   zero unless n is not greater than or equal to 1.

Answer (score 2):

Add a short circuit evaluation, `||` (logical OR) :

```
for s in $(seq 1 5); do
   (( s == 3 )) || echo "$s"
done
```

`(( s == 3 ))` checks if `$s` is equal to `3`, if not (`||`) `echo` the number.

With the reverse check (`$s` not equal to `3`) and logical AND (`&&`):

```
for s in $(seq 1 5); do
   (( s != 3 )) && echo "$s"
done
```

---

The classic way, `if` with `test` (`[`), non-equity `test`:

```
for s in $(seq 1 5); do
    if [ "$s" -ne 3 ]; then
        echo "$s"
    fi
done
```

Reverse `test`, equity check:

```
for s in $(seq 1 5); do
    if [ "$s" -eq 3 ]; then
        continue
    fi
    echo "$s"
done
```

`continue` will make the loop control to go at the top rather than evaluating the following commands.

---

There is also a `bash` keyword `[[` which behaves similarly in most cases but more robust.

Answer (score 2):

You can use BASH arithmetic construct `((...))` like this:

```
s1=3  # skip this
s2=6  # upper count

for ((i=1; i<s2; i+=(i==s1-1?2:1) )); do echo $i; done

1
2
4
5
```

About: `i+=(i==s1-1?2:1)`

In the for loop instead of always incrementing `i` by `1` here we are incrementing `i` by `2` when `i` is `1` less then the number to be skipped.

---

**Alternatively solution** using BASH array:

```
arr=({1..5})    # populate 1 to 5 in an array
unset arr[s1-1] # delete element s1-1
# print the array
printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"

1
2
4
5
```

Comment: You could simplify that a little to `i += (i==si-1 ? 2 : 1)` (or possibly even `i += 1 + (si-1 == i)`, depending on how readable you find treating a boolean as an integer).

Comment: Thanks @chepner, yes `for ((i=1; i<s2; i+=(i==s1-1?2:1) )); do echo $i; done` is definitely more readable.