# How to remove lines appear only once in a file using bash

Tags: bash, awk, uniq

How can I remove lines appear only once in a file in bash?

For example, file foo.txt has:

```
1
2
3
3
4
5
```

after process the file, only

```
3
3
```

will remain.

Note the file is sorted already.

Comment: If there are numbers `1,3,1,3` is that the order of output or can you handle `1,1,3,3,`?

Comment: @James Brown the file is sorted already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your duplicated lines are consecutives, you can use `uniq`

```
uniq -D file
```

from the man pages:

> -D     print all duplicate lines

Comment: if the duplicated lines aren't consecutives, you must sort them first
    `sort file | uniq -D`

Comment: Note that `-D` is a _GNU-specific_ extension and won't work with BSD/macOS `uniq`.

Answer (score 3):

Just loop the file twice:

```
$ awk 'FNR==NR {seen[$0]++; next} seen[$0]>1' file file
3
3
```

- firstly to count how many times a line occurs: `seen[ record ]` keeps track of it as an array.
- secondly to print those that appear more than once

Comment: This answer will preserve the original order and it will work even if input data is unsorted ++

Answer (score 2):

Using single pass awk:

```
awk '{freq[$0]++} END{for(i in freq) for (j=1; freq[i]>1 && j<=freq[i]; j++) print i}' file

3
3
```

- Using `freq[$0]++` we count and store frequency of each line.
- In the `END` block if `frequency` is greater than `1` then we print those lines as many times as the frequency.

Comment: nice! I like your [`for-loop` guru approaches](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40110515/1983854)

Answer (score 2):

Using awk, single pass:

```
$ awk 'a[$0]++ && a[$0]==2 {print} a[$0]>1' foo.txt
3
3
```

If the file is unordered, the output will happen in the order duplicates are found in the file due to the solution not buffering values.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a **POSIX-compliant `awk` alternative to the GNU-specific `uniq -D`**:

```
awk '++seen[$0] == 2; seen[$0] >= 2' file
```

<sup>This turned out to be just a shorter reformulation of [James Brown's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40176677/45375).</sup>

Unlike `uniq`, this command doesn't *strictly* require the duplicates to be grouped, but the output order will only be predictable if they are.

That is, if the duplicates aren't grouped, the output order is determined by the the relative ordering of the *2nd* instances in each set of duplicates, and in each set the 1st and the 2nd instances will be printed together.

**For *unsorted* (ungrouped) data** (and if preserving the input order is also important), consider:

- [fedorqui's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40175379/45375) (elegant, but requires reading the file *twice*)
- [anubhava's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40175389/45375) (single-pass solution, but a little more cumbersome).

Comment: It's shorter, I'll drink to that.

Comment: @JamesBrown: Thanks - I didn't actually notice (and up-voted) your answer until after I'd written mine.